# Momentum of a charged particle in a magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, momentum, gauge-invariance

In the presence of a magnetic field, the canonical momentum of a charge particle changes from $p_{i}\equiv mv^i$ to $\pi_{i}\equiv p_{i}+eA_{i}$, where $e$ is the charge of the particle.

1. It is possible to define another kind of canonical momentum $\tilde{\pi}_{i}=p_{i}-eA_{i}$?
2. How can you show that this new definition of momentum is not gauge-invariant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as $qV$ is potential energy, $q \vec{A}$ could easily be considered to be 'potential momentum', while ordinary momentum could be considered 'kinetic momentum'.
$${\vec p}_{total}={\vec p}_{kinetic}+{\vec p}_{potential}$$

While this 'total momentum' is not gauge invariant, conservation of total momentum is gauge invariant, and that is the critical item.

Comment: Ah, I see! So, under a gauge transformation, $\tilde{\pi} \rightarrow \tilde{\pi}-e\nabla\chi$ for a gauge transformation $A\rightarrow A+\nabla\chi$, which is why $\tilde{\pi}$ is not gauge invariant?

Comment: That's right.  The gauge choice is time invariant and so the time derivative will cause the extra gauge term to drop out when you look at conservation of momentum.